# Python, delete specific names from list

Tags: python, list

First I select the group named `hairSystem1Follicles` and make a `list` of it
then I make an empty `list` with things to delete

I have tried two things, but both are useless.
I would like it to isolate all the elements in the list with the name `curve1` `curve2` etc. not the other things in the list which are named `loftfolicle*`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list is named "hairSystem1Follicles".

Try this list comprehension:

```
isolated = [ name for name in hairSystem1Follicles if name != "loftfolicle" ]
```